# JavaScript Stops in Chrome on Postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I have a standard asp.net file upload control with a standard asp.net button on a simple .aspx page. When the button is clicked, I do my file upload. I wanted to show a simple "uploading..." gif animation.

At first, I achieved it by adding a simple JavaScript function to the OnClientClick of the button, like so...

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_Upload" OnClienClick="return ShowMyUploadingDiv();" OnClick="btn_Upload_Click" />
```

My javascript code, looked like this:

```
function ShowMyUploadingDiv() {
     $('#uploadingDiv').show();
     return true;
}
```

Since my JavaScript function returns true, my uploadingDiv (which had an animated .gif in it) shows up, and then does the PostBack. Golden.

The problem? Well, IE has this little issue where all .gifs stop their animation on PostBack. Great. While researching the issue, I found that you can update a .gif's source with a setTimeout function, but realized that there was another issue with that. Onward...

So, I went a different route, and used jQuery to animate a graphic. Everything now works perfectly. The uploadingDiv pops up, and my files upload while the jQuery animation routine plays.

The next problem? Now the JavaScript that pops open the div and plays the animation doesn't run all the way through in Chrome!

TL;DR
Chrome doesn't seem to keep running JavaScript after a PostBack.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the parenthesis at end of handler - try removing them?

Comment: Can you show some more of your code please to establish the context for your other code samples. I'm not getting it from your description.